Why is HttpClient not able to get the response for this site?
It is running into timeout. But the site seems to work normally in browsers.
string uri = "https://helpx.adobe.com/de/robohelp/using/basics-of-conditional-content.html";
HttpClientHandler handler1 = new();
HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient(handler1);
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage1 = new(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
HttpResponseMessage resp1 = client1.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage1).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
string content = await resp1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(content);

I have executed this simple code in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10, .NET 8, but it runs into timeout waiting for the response.

You also need to dispose your disposables.

The site likely blocks because of empty headers. When added it work.
string uri = "https://helpx.adobe.com/de/robohelp/using/basics-of-conditional-content.html";
HttpClientHandler handler1 = new();
HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient(handler1);
client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "curl/8.9.1");
client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage1 = new(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
HttpResponseMessage resp1 = client1.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage1).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
string content = await resp1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(content);

Btw, the code can be simplified. Also don't mix async and sync code.
string uri = "https://helpx.adobe.com/de/robohelp/using/basics-of-conditional-content.html";
using (HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient())
{
    client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "curl/8.9.1");
    client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
    string content = await client1.GetStringAsync(uri);
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}


I added a using around the HttpClient as it's disposable.

While this code will work, it has several unexpected drawbacks.

@Enigmativity HttpClient is meant to be re-used.

@Ghasanغسان - No, that's not true. It's been designed poorly and as a work around it is suggested, as a weak solution, to let the instance last forever. But that has pitfalls. My view is that, as a good developer, you understand the poor design and write your code in a manner that makes it work properly. That said, the more important rule is disposables shall always be explicitly disposed.
